# How to edit embed field value in Discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, embed

So I am trying to edit one field in an embed.
The fetched embed looks like this:

```
MessageEmbed {
  type: 'rich',
  title: null,
  description: null,
  url: null,
  color: 5763719,
  timestamp: null,
  fields: [
    { name: 'Suggestie', value: 'test1', inline: false },
    { name: 'Status', value: 'Open', inline: true },
    { name: 'ID', value: 'SPogb', inline: true },
    { name: 'User ID', value: '291272018773671937', inline: true },
    {
      name: 'Opmerking van staff:',
      value: 'Geen opmerking',
      inline: false
    }
  ],
  thumbnail: null,
  image: null,
  video: null,
  author: {
    name: 'Nigel#7777',
    url: undefined,
    iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/291272018773671937/b2637472f4502b2b2280b6302d3f666c.webp',
    proxyIconURL: 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/I_MfeMd6YbK_NxsY_kG-k7P6hiytpXx3tNk9ZJdd9lg/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/291272018773671937/b2637472f4502b2b2280b6302d3f666c.webp'
  },
  provider: null,
  footer: null
}
```

I am trying to edit the Status field value from Open to Approved, but I have no idea how to achieve this. I currently have:

```js
const kanaal = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.kanalen.suggestieKanaal)
        const ID = interaction.options.getString('id');
        let correcteSuggest;
        kanaal.messages.fetch({limit: 50}).then(messages => {
            const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot);
            botMessages.forEach(msg => {
                if(msg.embeds[0].fields[2].value === interaction.options.getString('id')) {
                    correcteSuggest = msg;
                }
            })
            console.log(correcteSuggest.embeds[0].fields)
            // correcteSuggest.edit(embeds[0].fields[1] = ({name: "Status", value: "Approved", inline: true}))
            // const editedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(correcteSuggest.embeds[0]).fields[3]



        })
```

The commented stuff I tried but did not seem to work. I have seen other people get the embed and do like .setDescription, but I don't know how that would work with .setField since there are more then one fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by doing:

```js
correcteSuggest.embeds[0].fields.find(f => f.name === "Status").value = "Approved";

correcteSuggest.edit({embeds: [correcteSuggest.embeds[0]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

your logic of editing the embed is right but the way is wrong. Discord.JS doesn't actually just update one field, it updates the whole message so we'll need to change the way to a whole new MessageEmbed.

```js
const kanaal = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.kanalen.suggestieKanaal)
const ID = interaction.options.getString('id');
let correcteSuggest;
kanaal.messages.fetch({
    limit: 50
}).then(messages => {
    const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot);
    botMessages.forEach(msg => {
        if (msg.embeds[0].fields[2].value === interaction.options.getString('id')) {
            correcteSuggest = msg;
        }
    })
    if (correcteSuggest.embeds[0]) {
        const editedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(correcteSuggest.embeds[0]);
        editedEmbed.fields[1].value = "Approved";
        correcteSuggest.edit({
            embeds: [editedEmbed]
        });
    }
})
```